# Android - How to change EditText background color from Settings Activity?

Tags: android, background, android-edittext

I have an `editText` in a fragment and I have a settings `activity`. So, I want to change the `background color` of the `editText` from setting activity. I know how to change background from the same activity but not from different activities.

**Any Idea how can I achieve that?**

Comment: @PrinceAli this is for Activity to Activity & I want for fragment and Activity.

Comment: Are you doing it using SharedPrefs?

Comment: @PrinceAli No. I am using only Intent.

Comment: Do share your code please.